# LTE Mikrotik NAT not works

Tags: firewall, nat, port-forwarding, mikrotik

I've and LTE Mikrotik HRBwAPGR-5HacD2HnD and QNAP NAS server.
My need was to route trafic to QNAP server (192.168.88.102) from internet(using DDNS and so on) but not able to perform it, maybe I'm setting up the wrong NAT rules?

ip export output:

```
# jan/12/2024 15:47:44 by RouterOS 6.49.7
# software id = 2DFH-9ZZK
#
# model = RBwAPGR-5HacD2HnD
# serial number = HDG08GNT5V5
/ip pool
add name=dhcp ranges=192.168.88.10-192.168.88.254
/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp disabled=no interface=bridge name=defconf
/ip address
add address=192.168.88.1/24 comment=defconf interface=bridge network=192.168.88.0
/ip cloud
set ddns-enabled=yes ddns-update-interval=5m
/ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.88.0/24 comment=defconf dns-server=192.168.88.1 gateway=192.168.88.1
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes
/ip dns static
add address=192.168.88.1 comment=defconf name=router.lan
/ip neighbor discovery-settings
set discover-interface-list=LAN
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept established,related,untracked" connection-state=established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=invalid
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept ICMP" protocol=icmp
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept to local loopback (for CAPsMAN)" dst-address=127.0.0.1
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop all not coming from LAN" disabled=yes in-interface-list=!LAN
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept in ipsec policy" ipsec-policy=in,ipsec
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept out ipsec policy" ipsec-policy=out,ipsec
add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward comment="defconf: fasttrack" connection-state=established,related
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept established,related, untracked" connection-state=established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=invalid
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop all from WAN not DSTNATed" connection-nat-state=!dstnat connection-state=new disabled=yes in-interface-list=WAN
add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.88.102 dst-port=8080,80,443,8081 log=yes protocol=tcp
add action=accept chain=output disabled=yes dst-address=192.168.88.102 dst-port=8080 protocol=tcp
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="defconf: masquerade" ipsec-policy=out,none out-interface-list=WAN
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat dst-port=8080 in-interface=bridge log=yes protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.88.102 to-ports=8080
/ip upnp
set enabled=yes
/ip upnp interfaces
add interface=ether2 type=internal
add interface=ether1 type=internal
add interface=bridge type=internal
```

log output:

```
dstnat: in:bridge out:(unknown 0), src-mac 14:7d:da:db:da:93, proto TCP (SYN), 192.168.88.253:57545->185.115.5.162:8080, len 48
forward: in:bridge out:bridge, src-mac 14:7d:da:db:da:93, proto TCP (SYN), 192.168.88.253:57545->192.168.88.102:8080, NAT 192.168.88.253:57545->(185.115.5.162:8080->192.168.88.102:8080), len 48
```

Comment: Does your LTE interface has a public reachable IP?
Also, there is DST-NAT on interface called "bridge", but nothing about LTE interface.

Comment: it recommends to put it to bridge , it has DDNS set

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON The nat table has a `masquerade` rule on the WAN interface group, which is correct, but I don't think the LTE interface should be on a bridge, that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I would suggest don't put the lte interface on a bridge, make sure it's in the WAN interface group, and make sure it's assigning an ip and gateway properly